# Button inside the search

Tags: html, css

How to force my button to show up over the input? It wants to go to the second line:
[image]

What I would like:

[image]

The input should be 100% wide.

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius:30px;
  padding-right:50px;
}

button {
  border-radius:30px;
  margin-left:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="search for something"/>
<button>search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the contaienr (div)  a `position: relative` and then position the button absolute:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-right: 4em;
}

button {
  border-radius:30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search for something"/>
  <button>search</button>
</div>
```

PS: Don't forget to set a `padding-right` for the input to offset the input text to the button width.

Comment: Doesn't the OP want `right: 0;` instead of `left: 0;` ?

Comment: @David thank you for the hint. I mixed the images